# Heroku fails to connect Redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis

I open an app that has been sleeping for nearly one year. Rediscloud cancelled the DB in the meanwhile.
I have a new Rediscloud DB, with REDISCLOUD_URL on a **redis://default:(key)@redis-(path)** format.
But Sidekiq cannot connect on Rediscloud.

My Redislabs.com linked with my app asserts 'This subscription
does not contain any databases'

Do I have to launch/initialize rediscloud DB in some way ? Does the `default:` generate a missing authorization ACL ? Or is the problem due to my redis gem version 4 ?

Here is my Gemfile abstrac. It used to work perfectly one year ago, before I put the app on sleep. That's why I haven't changed versions yet, and I'm still on heroku-18 :

```
ruby '2.6.5'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.2', '>= 6.0.2.1'
gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sidekiq-failures', '~> 1.0'
```

Here are my logs :

```
2021-12-03T11:25:25.593016+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.3/lib/redis/client.rb:230:in `process'
2021-12-03T11:25:25.593016+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.3/lib/redis/client.rb:125:in `call'
2021-12-03T11:25:25.593016+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.3/lib/redis.rb:286:in `block in info'
2021-12-03T11:25:25.593017+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.3/lib/redis.rb:52:in `block in synchronize'
2021-12-03T11:25:25.593017+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:235:in `mon_synchronize'
2021-12-03T11:25:25.593017+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.3/lib/redis.rb:52:in `synchronize'
2021-12-03T11:25:25.593018+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.3/lib/redis.rb:285:in `info'
2021-12-03T11:25:25.593018+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.6/lib/sidekiq.rb:118:in `block in redis_info'
2021-12-03T11:25:25.593018+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.6/lib/sidekiq.rb:97:in `block in redis'
2021-12-03T11:25:25.593019+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:65:in `block (2 levels) in with'
2021-12-03T11:25:25.593019+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:64:in `handle_interrupt'
2021-12-03T11:25:25.593019+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:64:in `block in with'
2021-12-03T11:25:25.593019+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:61:in `handle_interrupt'
2021-12-03T11:25:25.593020+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:61:in `with'
2021-12-03T11:25:25.593020+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.6/lib/sidekiq.rb:94:in `redis'
2021-12-03T11:25:25.593020+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.6/lib/sidekiq.rb:112:in `redis_info'
2021-12-03T11:25:25.593020+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.6/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:61:in `run'
2021-12-03T11:25:25.593020+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sidekiq-6.0.6/bin/sidekiq:12:in `<top (required)>'
2021-12-03T11:25:25.593021+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/sidekiq:23:in `load'
2021-12-03T11:25:25.593021+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/sidekiq:23:in `<top (required)>'
2021-12-03T11:25:25.593022+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
2021-12-03T11:25:25.593022+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
2021-12-03T11:25:25.593022+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
2021-12-03T11:25:25.593022+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:465:in `exec'
2021-12-03T11:25:25.593022+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2021-12-03T11:25:25.593022+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
2021-12-03T11:25:25.593022+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
2021-12-03T11:25:25.593023+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27:in `dispatch'
2021-12-03T11:25:25.593023+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
2021-12-03T11:25:25.593023+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18:in `start'
2021-12-03T11:25:25.593023+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
2021-12-03T11:25:25.593023+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124:in `with_friendly_errors'
2021-12-03T11:25:25.593023+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
2021-12-03T11:25:25.593024+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/bin/bundle:113:in `load'
2021-12-03T11:25:25.593024+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/bin/bundle:113:in `<main>'
2021-12-03T11:25:25.594276+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/redis-4.1.3/lib/redis/client.rb:362:in `rescue in establish_connection': Error connecting to Redis on redis-11993.c1.eu-west-1-3.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com:11993 (SocketError) (Redis::CannotConnectError)
```

My Redis configuration :

```
**Gemfile**
  gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'

**Gemfile.lock**
  redis (4.1.3)

**config/cable.yml:**
development:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDISCLOUD_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" } %>
  channel_prefix: _wadzatsong_development

test:
  adapter: test

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDISCLOUD_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" } %> 
  channel_prefix: _wadzatsong_production



**/config/initializers/redis.rb:**
   $redis = Redis.new
    
   if Rails.env=="production"
     url = ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"]
   elsif Rails.env=="development"
     url = "redis://localhost:6379/1"
   end
    
   if url
     Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
       config.redis = { url: url }
     end

     Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
       config.redis = { url: url }
     end
     $redis = Redis.new(:url => url)
   end
```

On development it fails too :

```
    rails s

    Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-12-04 16:53:56 +0100
      
    PG::ConnectionBad (could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
    ):
```

Comment: Can you please post your redis configuration

Comment: Done it right now @Maxence :)

Comment: Also you didn't say if it works in development ? I don't see anything wrong, maybe double check environment variable "REDISCLOUD_URL" is correct

Comment: Yes @Maxence I guess it's a tough problem. It doesn't work on development either :                                                                                                                    Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-12-04 16:53:56 +0100
  
PG::ConnectionBad (could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
):

Comment: @Maxence, how can I double-check the environment variable ? Don't I have to initialize my Rediscloud, after Redis has deleted it for it had been sleeping for too long ?